# C++ Linking error : the compiler can not find the definition of the function

Tags: c++, linker, makefile

I have a file Cache.cpp that has a corresponding header file Cache.h and another NetFunctions.cpp that has a corresponding header file NetFunction.h.

I have a makefile that looks like this

```
all: net cache
    g++ main.cpp ../obj/NetFunctions.o ../obj/Cache.o -o ../bin/main
net: NetFunctions.cpp
    g++ -c NetFunctions.cpp -o ../obj/NetFunctions.o
cache: Cache.cpp net
    g++ -c Cache.cpp ../obj/NetFunctions.o -o ../obj/Cache.o
```

Now NetFunctions.cpp has a function getNFHTML(string) defined there, which is used in Cache.cpp. I have checked the header files and they look fine with all the functions, declared there and header files properly included.

However, when I make, I get the following linker error

```
../obj/Cache.o: In function `Cache::getHTML(std::basic_string<char,  std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
Cache.cpp:(.text+0x19ee): undefined reference to `getNFHTML(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1***
```

Can someone help me with this? What is the problem?

I have also referred to this post [C++ Linking error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481409/c-linking-error), but it was of no help to me.

### Edit

Here is the code:
NetFunctions.h

```
#ifndef NET
#define NET 1

#include "commons.h"

bool serv_bind(struct addrinfo **servinfo, struct addrinfo **p, int *sockfd, int *yes);
void* get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa);
string getNFHTML(string website);  
string saveHeaders(string);
//bool getNFHTML(string request, string last_modified, string *response);
extern bool useCache;

#endif
```

NetFunctions.cpp

```
    #include "NetFunctions.h"
    string getNFHTML(string request)
    {
    // a lot of code
    }
```

Cache.cpp

```
#include "NetFunctions.h"
#include "Cache.h"
string Cache::getHTML(string request)
{
//some code
    string response = getNFHTML(request);
//some code
}
```

I have stripped the files as they contained several hundred lines

Comment: When you bold the error, you get parts of the error message eaten up by HTML. Please don't do that. Leave it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the problem, but I put it in an answer so it will be better formated.

Your makefile doesn't handle dependencies very well. Try this one instead:

```
.PHONY: all
all: ../bin/main

../bin/main: main.cpp ../obj/NetFunctions.o ../obj/Cache.o
    g++ $^ -o $@

../obj/NetFunctions.o: NetFunctions.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@

../obj/Cache.o: Cache.cpp 
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

For the `../bin/main` target, the variable `$^` means to take all prerequisites, and `$@` is the target of the rule. This means you can add as many object files as you like, and all will be linked.

For the compilation of the source to object files, the `$<` variable is the first prerequisite. This will also make it easier to copy/paste the targets if you add more files.

The rules also make sure that when you build `../bin/main` all files it depends on will be built properly.

The first target, `all`, will be the default if you run `make` without specifying a target. It has been marked as a *phony* target, because it doesn't produce a file called `all`.

Note that I'm basing this on GNU make, which is standard in almost all Linux distributions, and in Cygwin/MingW. If you use BSD make the variables might change.

Comment: hey in the last target did u mean ../obj/Cache.o: Cache.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
cache: Cache.cpp net
    g++ -c Cache.cpp ../obj/NetFunctions.o -o ../obj/Cache.o
```

to:

```
cache: Cache.cpp net
    g++ -c Cache.cpp -o ../obj/Cache.o
```

Better yet, get rid of the dummy targets and turn on compiler warnings:

```
../bin/main: ../obj/NetFunctions.o ../obj/Cache.o
    g++ -Wall main.cpp ../obj/NetFunctions.o ../obj/Cache.o -o $@
../obj/NetFunctions.o: NetFunctions.cpp
    g++ -Wall -c NetFunctions.cpp -o $@
../obj/Cache.o: Cache.cpp
    g++ -Wall -c Cache.cpp -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

While your `Makefile` is pretty broken, it's pretty clear that **if** what you are saying:

> NetFunctions.cpp has a function getNFHTML(string) defined there

was true, then it would have worked. Therefore it must be that you are lying to us. Show the code for `getNFHTML` in `NetFunctions.cpp`, or at least the output from:

```
nm ../obj/NetFunctions.o | grep getNFHTML
```

Update:

Ok, what you told us *is* true. However, it appears that the target that is failing to link is called `test`, and there is no such target in your makefile.

I am guessing that *that* target is being linked without the required `NetFunctions.o` on the link line.

In any case, please update your question with *actual* link line that is failing.

Comment: This is the outpu of the command above "0000000000000100 T _Z9getNFHTMLSs"

Comment: hey thanks, my makefile was pretty broken as you said. I used the way Joachim told to write the makefile and it now gives no error. thanks